# dotnet restore failed when using nix-build, but works when under nix-shell --pure

Tags: .net-core, nuget, cross-compiling, nix, nixpkgs

I'm trying to use nix for building dotnet (sdk 5) projects.

The configuration is something like

```
stdenv.mkDerivation {
# builder = "${bash}/bin/bash";
# args = [ ./builder.sh ];
name = "mypackage";
src = ./.;
HOME = "/tmp/test-home";
DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT = 1;
nativeBuildInputs = [ nodejs ];
buildInputs = [ dotnet openssl cacert  ];
configurePhase = ''
  export HOME=$PWD/home
  runHook preConfigure
  dotnet nuget list source
  dotnet nuget locals all --list
  dotnet restore
  runHook postConfigure
'';
buildPhase = ''
  export DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
  export DOTNET_NOLOGO=1
  ${dotnet}/bin/dotnet publish ProjectDirectory --self-contained -r linux-x64 -c Release
'';
installPhase = ''
  mkdir -p $out/
'';
```

};

The `HOME` attribute in argument for `stdenv.mkDerivation` is for nix-shell only. Since nix-shell will inherit normal `$HOME`, I need to set `$HOME` to another empty directory to mimic behavior of build phase.

- When using `nix-shell` and run `dotnet restore` manually, it works fine.
- When using `nix-build`, build failed with following error when running `dotnet restore`

  Registered Sources:

  1. nuget.org [Enabled]
     https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
     http-cache: /build/PROJECTNAME/home/.local/share/NuGet/v3-cache
     global-packages: /build/PROJECTNAME/home/.nuget/packages/
     temp: /build/NuGetScratch
     plugins-cache: /build/PROJECTNAME/home/.local/share/NuGet/plugins-cache
     Determining projects to restore...
     /nix/store/fvfyn01fjmawvyn7vlhhrgkzyy6321wl-dotnet-sdk-5.0.202/sdk/5.0.202/NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/build/PROJECTNAME/PET-CT-machine-service.sln]
     /nix/store/fvfyn01fjmawvyn7vlhhrgkzyy6321wl-dotnet-sdk-5.0.202/sdk/5.0.202/NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   Name or service not known (api.nuget.org:443) [/build/PROJECTNAME/PET-CT-machine-service.sln]
     /nix/store/fvfyn01fjmawvyn7vlhhrgkzyy6321wl-dotnet-sdk-5.0.202/sdk/5.0.202/NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   Name or service not known [/build/tomopioneer/PET-CT-machine-service.sln]

What's the difference between `nix-build` and `nix-shell --pure` when `HOME` is manually set?

By reading code from github NixOS/nixpkgs repository, it seems several dotnet packages were using `nuget` manually and using `dotnet restore` with local source. Is that necessary?

---

I've make more tests about api.nuget.org.

running `curl https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -v`, I got:

- works fine when directly run under terminal of nixos
- works fine in `nix-shell --pure`
- error in `nix-build`, `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.nuget.org`

Comment: Nix builds are sandboxed by default https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix#Sandboxing

Answer (score 1):

`nix-shell` has network access which is not allowed in the sandbox that `nix-build` uses without a fixed output derivation.

> By reading code from github NixOS/nixpkgs repository, it seems several dotnet packages were using nuget manually and using dotnet restore with local source. Is that necessary?

With sandbox enabled yes.